# What could be stopping this code from working?

Tags: php, mysql

I recently decided to revive my university lab project but I am having a hard time figuring out how the login page got messed up. I recall it working fine but now anything i enter as username and password gets accepted (including the only correct login that is present in my database.

```
<?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?> 
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/validation_functions.php"); ?>
<?php
$username = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   // Process the form
   $username = $_POST["username"];
   $password = $_POST["password"];
 
   // validations
   $required_fields = array("username", "password"); 
   validate_presences($required_fields);
   if (empty($errors)) {
       // Attempt Login: Missing code
       $found_admin = attempt_login($username, $password);  
       if ($found_admin) {
           // Success
           redirect_to("admin.php");  
           $_SESSION["id"] = $found_admin["id"];
           $_SESSION["username"] = $found_admin["username"];
           // Mark user as logged in :Missing code
       } else {
           // Failure
           $_SESSION["message"] = "Username/password not found.";
       }
   }
} else {
   // This is probably a GET request
} // end: if (isset($_POST['submit'])) ?>

<?php $layout_context = "admin"; ?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?> 
<div id="main">
 <div id="navigation">
   &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div id="page">
<?php echo message(); ?>
<?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>
   <h2>Login</h2>
   <form action="login.php" method="post">
       <p>Username:
           <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo htmlentities($username); ?>" />
       </p>
       <p>Password:
           <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> </p>
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

Thats basically the code I was given in the lab to work with. The comments in the script are all hints that were already present.
These are some of the functions i think this script uses:

```
function find_admin_by_username($username) { global $connection;
    $safe_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $username);
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM admins ";
    $query .= "WHERE username = '{$safe_username}' "; $query .= "LIMIT 1";
    $admin_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query); confirm_query($admin_set);
    if($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($admin_set)) {
        return $admin;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function attempt_login($username, $password) {
    $admin = find_admin_by_username($username); 
    if ($admin) {
        // found admin, now check password
        if (password_check($password, $admin["hashed_password"])) {
            // password matches
            return $admin;
        } else {
            // password does not match
            return false;
        } 
    } else {
        // admin not found
        return false;
    } 
}

function password_encrypt($password) {
    $hash_format = "$2y$10$"; // Tells PHP to use Blowfish with a "cost" of 10
    $salt_length = 22; // Blowfish salts should be 22-characters or more $salt = generate_salt($salt_length);
    $format_and_salt = $hash_format . $salt;
    $hash = crypt($password, $format_and_salt);
    return $hash;
}
    
function generate_salt($length) {
    // Not 100% unique, not 100% random, but good enough for a salt // MD5 returns 32 characters
    $unique_random_string = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    // Valid characters for a salt are [a-zA-Z0-9./] $base64_string = base64_encode($unique_random_string);
    // But not '+' which is valid in base64 encoding $modified_base64_string = str_replace('+', '.', $base64_string);
    // Truncate string to the correct length
    $salt = substr($modified_base64_string, 0, $length);
    return $salt;
}
    
function password_check($password, $existing_hash) {
    // existing hash contains format and salt at start
    $hash = crypt($password, $existing_hash); if ($hash === $existing_hash) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Few things to note:

- yes i will secure my code from sql injection as soon as i get this thing working
- i am connected to my database successfully

Comment: You have `redirect_to("admin.php");` before you check the value of `$found_admin`

Comment: Ah okay that was a typo I apologise. The redirect_to("admin.php"); was meant to be a few lines lower. I have edited my post to show the correct current script.

Comment: What are all the `**` for? There's no highlighting in code blocks.

Comment: What does `var_dump($found_admin)` show when you enter a username/password that shouldn't be accepted?

Comment: Share your password_check function and where you get hashed_password code

Comment: Nope. I went back to my code, removed the part you mentioned was the problem but its still giving the same issue. I can login with any single character for username and password

Comment: @Barmer I am not sure where in the script should i place var_dump. I placed it just after "$found_admin = attempt_login($username, $password); 
" but got nothing

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should alway use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users. They are also a lot easier to use that reinventing the wheel like this

Answer (score 0):

After checking the code, I have changed the code in one place. The new function code below

```
    function attempt_login($username, $password) {
        $admin = find_admin_by_username($username); 
        if (!is_null($admin)) {
            // found admin, now check password
            if (password_check($password, $admin["hashed_password"])) {
                // password matches
                return $admin;
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Notice I have changed if($admin) to if(!is_null($admin)), you can update your code and check. This is because your function find_admin_by_username() may return null when admin not found in database and correct way to check null value is using the function is_null().

Comment: i altered the function as you mentioned and tried logging in. It made no difference. I can still enter anything as my login and proceed